# React Patterns for displaying SharePoint Lists in a single page

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have been trying out a few of the spfx-dev-samples over the last week to test the whole React / Office fabric setup. Now if I wanted create a single web part / container to render the following components:

**Component 1**

- List 1 tabular view
- List 2 Item:+ Add / delete actions

**Component 2**

- List 2 tabular view filtered on key field that matches a field on List 1
- List 2 Item: + Add / delete actions

  I guess I am asking there is an obvious (React) Pattern + Office Fabric components I should be using that will help me meet this requirement.

Comment: the fabric details list works great for tabular views.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you look at the components listed at https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components and read the best practices section of each component to see what it is and isn't meant for. Components like CommandBar and Pivot seem like they could be of use but again, verify that their intended use matches your scenario.

With regards to React: don't make your components too big. If you feel that the component is performing too many unrelated tasks, split it up in multiple components which should make it easier to maintain (and reuse!) them.

Comment: Thanks.  I the components do look the best approach. From my perspective, The SPFx web parts are fairly new, require  code only tooling and are targeted at discrete bits of visual functionality. Therefore, there is level of risk, in that a lot of coding is going to be needed to get an acceptable user experience - not quite as easy as (lower risk) PowerApps or Nintex Forms.   That said, I think I need to drop on to the code face and  build out the various (React) components. Not really for the faint hearted ;-) .